# angular routes en angularJs no muestra nada

Tags: angularjs

Estoy usando angularjs y uso el angular routes, esta es mi configuracion

```
var myapp = angular.module('automate', ["ngRoute"]);

myapp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl:"templates/home.html"
        })
        .when("/automate",{
            templateUrl: "templates/automates.html"
        })
});
```

Este es mi archivo Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Automan</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/icon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-animations.css">
</head>
<body>
<ng-view></ng-view>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/retinajs/dist/retina.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/jquery-unveil/jquery.unveil.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Pero a momento de correr la aplicacion, no me muestra nada en el ngview, peri tampoco hay algun error en consola

Answer (score 2):

Creo que te falta inicializar tu aplicación de angular con la directiva **ng-app="module_name"**. Sin esta directiva es imposible que angularjs se entere que tiene que ejecutarse automáticamente.

`<body ng-app="automate">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>`

Comment: Vaya.. ese es el problema, deberia dejar la pregunta o mejor la elimino, es muy novato de mi parte, disculpen

Comment: Pues como quieras, pero si la dejas, márcala como correcta para que otros que tengan el mismo problema sepan solucionarlo.

Comment: OK, de todas formas muchas gracias, igual soy novato en angular jajaja